# Getting error on running console application from .exe file

Tags: vb.net

My Console application (VB.NET) is working fine when I am running it in Visual Studio, but when I am running it by double clicking the .EXE file it is throwing the missing of assembly(dll), but DLL is present. What could be the reason.

Comment: have you hardcoded an absolute path to the dll or do you access it using Application.StartupPath

Comment: Is the DLL a reference to the project or are you P/Invoking it? You are missing a lot of vital information in your question: What is the exact error that is thrown (type + full error message)? How do you access the DLL (project reference, P/Invoke, other)? Where is it located when referenced by your code? Where is it "present" when you run the application?